# How can I create a new file in Xcode without adding it to any target?

Tags: xcode, file

Sometimes I just want to create a plain text file for storing JSON or whatever.

Normally I would just press <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to create a new file in Xcode. But it always adds the created file to the project! That means I need to delete it from the project every time!

I thought that this was because I checked the target that I want to add the file to here:

[image]

So I unchecked "TestingArea" and created the file. But it *still* adds the file to the project!

I know that I can use the TextEdit app, but since I have lots of apps placed on the Dock, finding it takes a long time.

Any solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by "still" adds the file to the project?  It should no longer be a part of any of the targets, but it still may be visible within your viewer.

Comment: Yeah, I can see it in the left pane. That is exactly what I don't want. Doesn't that mean the file will be in the ipa file and can be found by `NSBundle.pathForResource`? @FishStix

Comment: No.  When you click on the file, the right pane should display which targets it is a part of.  If it's not checked, it won't go in the bundle of that target.